# Room Paging library always return null LiveData?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, android-paging-library

I am trying to use a paging library in my project but when I try to recieve `LiveData<PageList<Entity>> data` it's value is always null. My implementation looks like this:

**DAO**

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM entity")
fun getAll(): DataSource.Factory<Int, Entity>
```

**ViewModel**

```
    val pagedListConfig = PagedList.Config.Builder()
            .setEnablePlaceholders(false)
            .setPageSize(20).build()

    val data = LivePagedListBuilder(database.getAll(), pagedListConfig)
                .build()
                .value
```

The data variable is always null.

Comment: Possible duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44428389/livedata-getvalue-returns-null-with-room

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very simple, you're still working LiveData, so it should be just:

```
val data = LivePagedListBuilder(database.getAll(), pagedListConfig).build()
```

Then data is LiveData which you should observe.