# Room Entity's data is stored correctly but is retrieved as null

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, android-livedata

**What i'm trying to do**

When my app starts, i'm using a fragment which uses an `AutoCompleteTextView` and the Places SDK to fetch a `Place` object when the user makes a selection. When that happens, i store that selected Place (as a WeatherLocation entity) through my Repository class in my Room database by calling `repository.storeWeatherLocation(context,placeId)` and then fetching the weather details again if needed.

**What's happening**

The `suspend fun storeWeatherLocationAsync` is calling the `fetchCurrentWeather()` & `fetchWeeklyWeather()` because from what i was able to log, the `previousLocation` variable is null despite the database inspector showing that older weather location data is already present.

**Crash details**

My app is crashing stating that my LocationProvider's `getCustomLocationLat()` is returning null (occurs in `fetchCurrentWeather()`). The thing is that the location that the user selected is successfully stored in my Room database (checked using Database Inspector) so how is this function returning null?

**UPDATE**:

After doing some more testing with the debugger and logcat, I've found out that  the `WeatherLocation` data is being saved in Room when the app is running. Once it crashes and I reopen it though, that data is once again null. What am I missing here? Am i deleting the previous data somehow? Am i not actually caching it correctly in Room?

Database class:

```
@Database(
    entities = [CurrentWeatherEntry::class,WeekDayWeatherEntry::class,WeatherLocation::class],
    version = 16
)
abstract class ForecastDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun currentWeatherDao() : CurrentWeatherDao
    abstract fun weekDayWeatherDao() : WeekDayWeatherDao
    abstract fun weatherLocationDao() : WeatherLocationDao

    // Used to make sure that the ForecastDatabase class will be a singleton
    companion object {
        // Volatile == all of the threads will have immediate access to this property
        @Volatile private var instance:ForecastDatabase? = null
        private val LOCK = Any() // dummy object for thread monitoring

        operator fun invoke(context:Context) = instance ?: synchronized(LOCK) {
            // If the instance var hasn't been initialized, call buildDatabase()
            // and assign it the returned object from the function call (it)
            instance ?: buildDatabase(context).also { instance = it }
        }

        /**
         * Creates an instance of the ForecastDatabase class
         * using Room.databaseBuilder().
         */
        private fun buildDatabase(context: Context) =
            Room.databaseBuilder(context.applicationContext,
                ForecastDatabase::class.java, "forecast.db")
                //.addMigrations(MIGRATION_2_3) // specify an explicit Migration Technique
                .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                .build()
    }
}
```

Here's the Repository class:

```
class ForecastRepositoryImpl(
    private val currentWeatherDao: CurrentWeatherDao,
    private val weekDayWeatherDao: WeekDayWeatherDao,
    private val weatherLocationDao: WeatherLocationDao,
    private val locationProvider: LocationProvider,
    private val weatherNetworkDataSource: WeatherNetworkDataSource
) : ForecastRepository {

    init {
        weatherNetworkDataSource.apply {
            // Persist downloaded data
            downloadedCurrentWeatherData.observeForever { newCurrentWeather: CurrentWeatherResponse? ->
                persistFetchedCurrentWeather(newCurrentWeather!!)
            }
            downloadedWeeklyWeatherData.observeForever { newWeeklyWeather: WeeklyWeatherResponse? ->
                persistFetchedWeeklyWeather(newWeeklyWeather!!)
            }
        }
    }

    override suspend fun getCurrentWeather(): LiveData<CurrentWeatherEntry> {
        return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            initWeatherData()
            return@withContext currentWeatherDao.getCurrentWeather()
        }
    }

    override suspend fun getWeekDayWeatherList(time: Long): LiveData<out List<WeekDayWeatherEntry>> {
        return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            initWeatherData()
            return@withContext weekDayWeatherDao.getFutureWeather(time)
        }
    }

    override suspend fun getWeatherLocation(): LiveData<WeatherLocation> {
        return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            return@withContext weatherLocationDao.getWeatherLocation()
        }
    }

    private suspend fun initWeatherData() {
        // retrieve the last weather location from room
        val lastWeatherLocation = weatherLocationDao.getWeatherLocation().value

        if (lastWeatherLocation == null ||
            locationProvider.hasLocationChanged(lastWeatherLocation)
        ) {
            fetchCurrentWeather()
            fetchWeeklyWeather()
            return
        }

        val lastFetchedTime = currentWeatherDao.getCurrentWeather().value?.zonedDateTime
        if (isFetchCurrentNeeded(lastFetchedTime!!))
            fetchCurrentWeather()

        if (isFetchWeeklyNeeded())
            fetchWeeklyWeather()
    }

    /**
     * Checks if the current weather data should be re-fetched.
     * @param lastFetchedTime The time at which the current weather data were last fetched
     * @return True or false respectively
     */
    private fun isFetchCurrentNeeded(lastFetchedTime: ZonedDateTime): Boolean {
        val thirtyMinutesAgo = ZonedDateTime.now().minusMinutes(30)
        return lastFetchedTime.isBefore(thirtyMinutesAgo)
    }

    /**
     * Fetches the Current Weather data from the WeatherNetworkDataSource.
     */
    private suspend fun fetchCurrentWeather() {
        weatherNetworkDataSource.fetchCurrentWeather(
            locationProvider.getPreferredLocationLat(),
            locationProvider.getPreferredLocationLong()
        )
    }

    private fun isFetchWeeklyNeeded(): Boolean {
        val todayEpochTime = LocalDate.now().toEpochDay()
        val futureWeekDayCount = weekDayWeatherDao.countFutureWeekDays(todayEpochTime)
        return futureWeekDayCount < WEEKLY_FORECAST_DAYS_COUNT
    }

    private suspend fun fetchWeeklyWeather() {
        weatherNetworkDataSource.fetchWeeklyWeather(
            locationProvider.getPreferredLocationLat(),
            locationProvider.getPreferredLocationLong()
        )
    }

    override fun storeWeatherLocation(context:Context,placeId: String) {
        GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            storeWeatherLocationAsync(context,placeId)
        }
    }

    override suspend fun storeWeatherLocationAsync(context: Context,placeId: String) {
        var isFetchNeeded: Boolean // a flag variable

        // Specify the fields to return.
        val placeFields: List<Place.Field> =
            listOf(Place.Field.ID, Place.Field.NAME,Place.Field.LAT_LNG)

        // Construct a request object, passing the place ID and fields array.
        val request = FetchPlaceRequest.newInstance(placeId, placeFields)

        // Create the client
        val placesClient = Places.createClient(context)

        placesClient.fetchPlace(request).addOnSuccessListener { response ->
            // Get the retrieved place object
            val place = response.place
            // Create a new WeatherLocation object using the place details
            val newWeatherLocation = WeatherLocation(place.latLng!!.latitude,
                place.latLng!!.longitude,place.name!!,place.id!!)

            val previousLocation = weatherLocationDao.getWeatherLocation().value
            if(previousLocation == null || ((newWeatherLocation.latitude != previousLocation.latitude) &&
                (newWeatherLocation.longitude != previousLocation.longitude))) {
                isFetchNeeded = true
                // Store the weatherLocation in the database
                persistWeatherLocation(newWeatherLocation)
                // fetch the data
                GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
                    // fetch the weather data and wait for it to finish
                    withContext(Dispatchers.Default) {
                        if (isFetchNeeded) {
                            // fetch the weather data using the new location
                            fetchCurrentWeather()
                            fetchWeeklyWeather()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            Log.d("REPOSITORY","storeWeatherLocationAsync : inside task called")
        }.addOnFailureListener { exception ->
            if (exception is ApiException) {
                // Handle error with given status code.
                Log.e("Repository", "Place not found: ${exception.statusCode}")
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Caches the downloaded current weather data to the local
     * database.
     * @param fetchedCurrentWeather The most recently fetched current weather data
     */
    private fun persistFetchedCurrentWeather(fetchedCurrentWeather: CurrentWeatherResponse) {
        fetchedCurrentWeather.currentWeatherEntry.setTimezone(fetchedCurrentWeather.timezone)
        // Using a GlobalScope since a Repository class doesn't have a lifecycle
        GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            currentWeatherDao.upsert(fetchedCurrentWeather.currentWeatherEntry)
        }
    }

    /**
     * Caches the selected location data to the local
     * database.
     * @param fetchedLocation The most recently fetched location data
     */
    private fun persistWeatherLocation(fetchedLocation: WeatherLocation) {
        GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            weatherLocationDao.upsert(fetchedLocation)
        }
    }

    /**
     * Caches the downloaded weekly weather data to the local
     * database.
     * @param fetchedWeeklyWeather  The most recently fetched weekly weather data
     */
    private fun persistFetchedWeeklyWeather(fetchedWeeklyWeather: WeeklyWeatherResponse) {

        fun deleteOldData() {
            val time = LocalDate.now().toEpochDay()
            weekDayWeatherDao.deleteOldEntries(time)
        }

        GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            deleteOldData()
            val weekDayEntriesList = fetchedWeeklyWeather.weeklyWeatherContainer.weekDayEntries
            weekDayWeatherDao.insert(weekDayEntriesList)
        }
    }
}
```

and here's the LocationProvider impl:

```
class LocationProviderImpl(
    private val fusedLocationProviderClient: FusedLocationProviderClient,
    context: Context,
    private val locationDao: WeatherLocationDao
) : PreferenceProvider(context), LocationProvider {
    private val appContext = context.applicationContext

    override suspend fun hasLocationChanged(lastWeatherLocation: WeatherLocation): Boolean {
        return try {
            hasDeviceLocationChanged(lastWeatherLocation)
        } catch (e:LocationPermissionNotGrantedException) {
            false
        }
    }

    /**
     * Makes the required checks to determine whether the device's location has
     * changed or not.
     * @param lastWeatherLocation The last known user selected location
     * @return true if the device location has changed or false otherwise
     */
    private suspend fun hasDeviceLocationChanged(lastWeatherLocation: WeatherLocation): Boolean {
        if(!isUsingDeviceLocation()) return false // we don't have location permissions or setting's disabled

        val currentDeviceLocation = getLastDeviceLocationAsync().await()
            ?: return false

        // Check if the old and new locations are far away enough that an update is needed
        val comparisonThreshold = 0.03
        return abs(currentDeviceLocation.latitude - lastWeatherLocation.latitude) > comparisonThreshold
                && abs(currentDeviceLocation.longitude - lastWeatherLocation.longitude) > comparisonThreshold
    }

    /**
     * Checks if the app has the location permission, and if that's the case
     * it will fetch the device's last saved location.
     * @return The device's last saved location as a Deferred<Location?>
     */
    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    private fun getLastDeviceLocationAsync(): Deferred<Location?> {
        return if(hasLocationPermission())
            fusedLocationProviderClient.lastLocation.asDeferredAsync()
         else
            throw LocationPermissionNotGrantedException()
    }

    /**
     * Checks if the user has granted the location
     * permission.
     */
    private fun hasLocationPermission(): Boolean {
        return ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(appContext,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    }

    /**
     * Returns the sharedPrefs value for the USE_DEVICE_LOCATION
     * preference with a default value of "true".
     */
    private fun isUsingDeviceLocation(): Boolean {
        return preferences.getBoolean(USE_DEVICE_LOCATION_KEY,false)
    }

    private fun getCustomLocationLat() : Double {
        val lat:Double? = locationDao.getWeatherLocation().value?.latitude
        if(lat == null) Log.d("LOCATION_PROVIDER","lat is null = $lat")
        return lat!!
    }

    private fun getCustomLocationLong():Double {
        return locationDao.getWeatherLocation().value!!.longitude
    }

    override suspend fun getPreferredLocationLat(): Double {
        if(isUsingDeviceLocation()) {
            try {
                val deviceLocation = getLastDeviceLocationAsync().await()
                    ?: return getCustomLocationLat()
                return deviceLocation.latitude
            } catch (e:LocationPermissionNotGrantedException) {
                return getCustomLocationLat()
            }
        } else {
            return getCustomLocationLat()
        }
    }

    override suspend fun getPreferredLocationLong(): Double {
        if(isUsingDeviceLocation()) {
            try {
                val deviceLocation = getLastDeviceLocationAsync().await()
                    ?: return getCustomLocationLong()
                return deviceLocation.longitude
            } catch (e:LocationPermissionNotGrantedException) {
                return getCustomLocationLong()
            }
        } else {
            return getCustomLocationLong()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not expect a Room `LiveData` to return anything but `null` from `getValue()` until an `Observer` has been added and has received its first value in its callback. `LiveData` is primarily an observable data holder and those created by Room are both lazy and asynchronous by design such that they will not start doing the background database work to make values available until an `Observer` is attached.

In situations like these from `LocationProviderImpl`:

```kotlin
    private fun getCustomLocationLat() : Double {
        val lat:Double? = locationDao.getWeatherLocation().value?.latitude
        if(lat == null) Log.d("LOCATION_PROVIDER","lat is null = $lat")
        return lat!!
    }

    private fun getCustomLocationLong():Double {
        return locationDao.getWeatherLocation().value!!.longitude
    }
```

you should instead use a `Dao` method with a more direct return type to retrieve the values, eg. in your `Dao` instead of something like this:

```kotlin
@Query("<your query here>")
fun getWeatherLocation(): LiveData<LocationEntity>
```

create and use one of these:

```kotlin
@Query("<your query here>")
suspend fun getWeatherLocation(): LocationEntity?

@Query("<your query here>")
fun getWeatherLocationSync(): LocationEntity?
```

which don't return until the result has been retrieved.

Comment: Well, good... but still, I landed in this question for a similar problem that happens with code **within an Observer**, that sometimes happens and sometimes not, and it's obvious that the bug is within RoomDb itself rather than my own code... and it's driving me totally insane... :-(

Answer (score 2):

**Preface**

It's too hard to be specific on your problem without full code and full understanding what does this code meant to do. If my following general suggestions (based on my guess and prediction) would be useless for you I recommend you either to add a link to you repository or simplify your use-case in order somebody could help you. But again - the more code you include in your minimal reproducible example the more chances you will not get specific answer.

**My guess about the source of trouble**

My guess (considering facts you described) that the main suspect in your trouble is overlay of your code's parts, that are asynchronous (for example, [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44428389/livedata-getvalue-returns-null-with-room?rq=1) is about problem with LiveData. But the same can be with suspend functions invoked in different coroutines and so on). So what are conditions of the problem I talk about? They are next - you save your data in local db, then you read your data, both actions are asynchronous, and there is a little time passed between first and second event. I really haven't understood whether described conditions are present in your case. If they aren't, I didn't guess right :-)

**My suggestions**

Try to check if described behaviour really causes your problem. There are many ways to do it. One of them - to change the case, when second operation (reading from local db) will follow the first one (writing to it). To do so you can put your second-operation in coroutine and add before some delay (I think, delay(1000) would be enough). As I've understood your functions - getCustomLocationLat(), getCustomLocationLong() - are first candidates to make this trick (may be there are another functions but it'll be easier to you to know them). If after this test-case, your problem is solved - you could think what appropriate changes you could make to guarantee that the second event will always be after the first one (it could depend on answers to some questions - 1) could you put both events in one coroutine? 2) could you replace unpacking value from LiveData with LiveData's observing or Deferred?)

Comment: Hi and thanks for trying  to solve my issue. I tried using `delay()` of various values (1s,5s,10s) but nothing seems to have changed. I'm still getting an NPE at the `getCustomLocationLat()` and the `previousLocation` also seems to be null at  every launch. The database inspectors shows that the new weather location is always saved in the db but at the start of every launch since previousLocation is null, that means it doesn't actually persist that data after a restart. Any ideas on that?

Comment: Show you RoomDatabase class (specifically its Builder part). Maybe it can help.

Comment: Added it in my post. Thank you

Comment: I don't know. Your database should be cleared after restart only if you increase your database version (current version is 16). I think you couldn't do that every time you met your problem?

Comment: Yeah i haven't modified it at all since the problem started occurring. I don't think the issue occurs here. The thing is that i don't have any other code running while I'm doing all these async processes so it seems really weird to me that it doesn't work. Any other ideas?